# Explanation of Pandas data normalization on Freecodecamp exercise?

Tags: python, pandas

I am studying through freecodecamp and one of the exercises ask to normalize a data:

> Normalize data by making 0 always good and 1 always bad. If the value of 'cholesterol' or 'gluc' is 1, make the value 0. If the value
> is more than 1, make the value 1.

I have not found a simple way to do it, but this example worked... but I didn't get how.
I'm looking for a quick explanation and which are the other ways to do it.

```
normal = df.loc[:,['cholesterol','gluc']] > 1
df.loc[:,['cholesterol','gluc']] = normal.astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is assigning the variable *normal* to a boolean array where each element is True if the corresponding cholesterol or glucose value is greater than 1, else False. This boolean array then gets converted to an int array (True is 1, False is 0) and assigning back to those cholesterol and glucose columns.

Another way of doing this could be with np.where.

Ex:

```
df['cholesterol'] = np.where(df['cholesterol'].values > 1, 1, 0)
```